# Ajax with Post Call

Tags: ajax, post, get

I am trying to convert my ajax call using GET to one using POST.
This is the one that works nicely with `GET`.
Changing the type to `POST` does not work.  Is the problem with the data string format?

```
 $.ajax({
    //type: "GET",  //works
    type: "POST",   // Does Not Work
    url: "/cgi-bin/my_perl.pl", // URL of the Perl script
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    //data format: "sid=" + sid + "&comments=" + comments,
    data: data_string,
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                            alert('AJAX Error');
    }, // error 
    // script call was successful 
    // data contains the JSON values returned by the Perl script 
    success: function(data){
            if(data.success) {
                    alert(data.success);
            }
            else if(data.error!=0) {
                    alert('We failed');
    } //else
    } // success
  }); // ajax
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"?

Comment: What's your console say?

Comment: I figured out my problem. My error was elsewhere. There was a debug statement in my code to print out a JSON without an exit following print. Somehow this caused the "AJAX Error" message. Once I got rid of my debug statement, both POST and GET worked!